# i get successfull in sendmail function, but not getting mail in gmail inbox

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendmail.exe

i have  extract sendmail.zip in my project and successfully run my mail function.but i can't get any mail in my inbox.  am i doing any mistake in php.ini file or sendmail.ini file and it will be helpfull if any one explain with detail code 
**my php.ini code:**

```
**[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
 SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
 smtp_port = 25
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
 ;sendmail_from = me@example.com
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\htdocs\comment_system\sendmail\sendmail.exe-t"
; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =
; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off
; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log = "C:\xampp\apache\logs\php_mail.log"
[SQL]
; http://php.net/sql.safe-mode
sql.safe_mode = Off**
```

---

**sendmail.ini**

```
; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=ssl

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=gmail

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

;debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=example.it@gmail.com
auth_password=...............

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=example.it@gmail.com

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post your Send mail code and Have you checked mail in Spam folder

Comment: Please check your spam!

Comment: yes rohit i have checked the spam as well and also tried my rediff no result i am using xampp and windows os

Comment: $to       = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject  = 'Testing sendmail.exe';
$message  = 'Hi, you just received an email using sendmail!';
$headers  = 'From: sender@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: sender@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
            'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
//$mail =mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 ini_set('sendmail_from', 'pramodhkumar.it@gmail.com');
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
 {
  echo "Email sent";
}
i get success message but no mail in inbox

Comment: I my experience with gmail -> they discard the emails without the right mx-record -> try a trash mail account maybe

Comment: i agree with @tingel2k

Comment: i got code from this link http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/

Comment: try a different send email

Comment: yes i have tried rediffmail but i think some thing wrong with smtp and smtp_port in php.ini or sendmail.ini file can any one explain what use to configure in both ini file as well ini_set() in php confusing in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your spam folder in googlemail.

If you can't find the spam folder see here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8393/how-to-make-gmail-spam-folder-always-visible